Is there a faster way to write different classes in python?
I am making the periodic table in python, but I was wondering if there was a different way to make multiple classes without having to write each individual property for each element. Is there a faster and easier way to do that/ make it so then I don't have to type as much.
This is my code
def gs(x):
    normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-=()"
    super_s = "ᴬᴮᶜᴰᴱᶠᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴼᴾQᴿˢᵀᵁⱽᵂˣʸᶻᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖ۹ʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾"
    res1 = x.maketrans(''.join(normal),''.join(super_s))
    return x.translate(res1)
class elements():
    def __init__(self, name,symbol,an, atomicweight, state, mp, bp, oxstates, eleconfig, atomicradius, electronegativity, valance):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.an = an #atomic number
        self.atomicweight = atomicweight
        self.state = state #metal, metalloid, gas or unknown at 0C and Classification
        self.mp = mp #melting point
        self.bp = bp #boiling point
        self.oxstates = oxstates #oxidation States (charges)
        self.eleconfig = eleconfig #electron Configuration
        self.atomicradius = atomicradius
        self.electronegativity = electronegativity
        self.valance = valance
        
    def properties(self):
        print(self.name, self.symbol, self.an, self.atomicweight, self.state, self.mp, self.bp, self.oxstates, self.eleconfig, self.atomicradius, self.electronegativity, self.valance)

hydrogenele =  elements('Element: Hydrogen', '\n Symbol: H', '\n Atomic number: 1', '\n Atomic Weight: 1.008u', '\n State at 0ᵒC: Gas (Reactive nonmetal)',
                        '\n Melting point: -259.1ᵒC', '\n Boiling point: -252.76ᵒC', '\n Oxidation States (Charges): ±1',
                        '\n Electron Configuration: 1s{}'.format(gs('1')), '\n Atomic Radius: 37pm', '\n Electronegativity: 2.18', '\n Valance electrons: 1')

heliumele = elements('Element: Helium', '\n Symbol: He', '\n Atomic Number: 2', '\n Atomic Weight: 4.002602u', '\n State at 0ᵒC: Gas (Noble gas)',
                    '\n Melting Point: -268.93', "\n Boiling Point: N/A", '\n Oxidation States (Charges): 0', 
                    '\n Electron Configuration: 1s{}'.format(gs('2')), '\n Atomic Radius: 31pm', "\n Electronegativity: N/A", '\n Valance Electrons: 2')

while True:
    select = input("Select the element by name: ")
    ele_name = f"{select}ele"
    if ele_name in locals():
        print(f"{locals()[ele_name].properties()}")
    elif 'h' in select:
        hc = input("Please select the number that corresponds to your problem: \n1. Don't know how to spell the element \n2. Info is incorrect \n3. Cancel \n")
        if '1' in hc:
            print("Filler")
        elif '2' in hc:
            print("Please go to this google forms to report problem \n(Link)")
        elif '3' in hc:
            continue
    else:
        print("Element not found \nType if you need help type 'h'")

This is my code, as you can see, there is a lot of properties that I decided to put in each element, and they are the one I think are the most important. The def gs(x) allows me to get super scripts. The ele after the element, allows me to search the name. Please help me.

Don't include the name of the attribute in the value of the attribute. 'Element: Hydrogen' should simply be: 'Hydrogen'. Similarly, if you want to print something with formatting then format it (using an f-string or equivalent) when you print it and do not store the formatting as part of the value.

Mote: normal is already a string so ''.join(normal) is casting to a list only to cast it back to a string.

You almost certainly don't want the newlines in your parameters, rather you want to handle that in your properties() method. You might also look at __str__() rather than properties().

rather than use locals() like this you almost certainly want to use a dictionary just for elements.

Consider using Data Classes:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    """Class for keeping track of an item in inventory."""
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def total_cost(self) -> float:
        return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand


Why show an example that is completely unrelated to the question? This only shortens the class definition; it doesn't address the question of how to better create the necessary instances.
